# What is causing Pypppeteer/Puppeteer to Timeout?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-chrome-headless, pyppeteer

I'm trying to scrape the contents of this site `http://www.intoaqua.com.au`  and I can't seem to identify what causes pypetteer to believe that the site has not finished loading/rendering. I suspect it's the vimeo video animation, but I'm not sure. I noticed that there are some scripts that get called as well, but JS is not my forte and I do not understand what the scripts do/if they are interfering with pyppeteer.

I have a more comprehensive scraper script that I'm trying to improve. I started from scratch for the url below to try to simply the debugging process. I've outlined what I've tried so far below the first block of code.

Per the [pypeteer README](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer/blob/dev/README.md), below is the most basic script to navigate to and take a screenshot of a webpage. When I try the block of code below, I get a Navigation TimeoutError after 30 sec (the default timeout arg).

For reference, I'm running the following setup:

- google-chrome-stable/now 95.0.4638.69-1 amd64
- pyppeteer==1.0.2
  I can successfully run the example provided in the README with the version of Chrome and pyppeteer listed above.

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

HEADLESS_CHROME_PATH = '/tmp/headless-chromium' # UPDATE to your headless-chrome path.
URL = '||ht||tp:||//||www.||intoaqua||.||com||.||au||'.replace("|","")
async def main():
    browser = await launch(
        executablePath=HEADLESS_CHROME_PATH,
    )
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('http://www.intoaqua.com.au')
    await page.screenshot({'path': 'example.png'})
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

This is the last pyppeteer log that I receive before the timeout occurs:
timestamp - pyppeteer.connection.CDPSession - DEBUG - RECV:

```
{
    "method":"Network.requestWillBeSent",
     "params":{
         "requestId":"5FB7370AE30F687E8313AB0170BC100A",
         "loaderId":"5FB7370AE30F687E8313AB0170BC100A",
        "documentURL":"||ht||tps||:||/||/pla||yer||.||vi||meo||.c||om||/||vi||de||o/||591||976007||?loo||p=||1&a||uto||pl||ay=||1&||ti||tle=||0&||by||li||ne||=0&||se||tVo||lu||me=||0&a||pi=1||&pl||ay||er||_i||d=||1||",
         "request":{
             "url":"||ht||tps||:||/||/pla||yer||.||vi||meo||.c||om||/||vi||de||o/||591||976007||?loo||p=||1&a||uto||pl||ay=||1&||ti||tle=||0&||by||li||ne||=0&||se||tVo||lu||me=||0&a||pi=1||&pl||ay||er||_i||d=||1||",
             "method":"GET",
             "headers":{
                 "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1",
                 "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36",
                 "accept-language":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
                 "Referer":"||ht||tp:||//||www.||intoaqua||.||com||.||au||/"
             },
             "mixedContentType":"none",
             "initialPriority":"VeryHigh",
             "referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade"
         },
         "timestamp":23541.14503,
         "wallTime":1647873017.37953,
         "initiator":{
             "type":"parser",
             "url":"||ht||tp:||//||www.||intoaqua||.||com||.||au||/",
             "lineNumber":813
         },
         "type":"Document",
         "frameId":"5AFC116D4AA48CAF019AA88708B716C1",
         "hasUserGesture":false
     }
}
```

I've tried all of the `page.goto waitUntil` options:

- `await page.goto('http://www.intoaqua.com.au', waitUntil='load')`
- `await page.goto('http://www.intoaqua.com.au', waitUntil='domcontentloaded')`
- `await page.goto('http://www.intoaqua.com.au', waitUntil='networkidle0')`
- `await page.goto('http://www.intoaqua.com.au', waitUntil='networkidle2')`

I've tried specifying addtional params for the browser launch:

```
browser = await launch(
    headless=True,
    executablePath=HEADLESS_CHROME_PATH,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors=True,
    userDataDir="/tmp/chrome/",
    args=[
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-gpu",
        "--single-process",
        "--no-zygote",
        "--disable-infobars",
        "--disable-web-security",
        "--disable-webgl",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "--ignore-certificate-errors",
        "--ignore-ssl-errors",
        "--incognito",
        "--no-referrers",
        "--no-proxy-server",
        "--stable-release-mode",
        "--enable-features=NetworkService",
    ],
    autoClose=False,
)
```

I've tried adding the headless detection script shared in the Intoli post: making-chrome-headless-undetectable (link removed to prevent spam flag getting raised).

Comment: Question has too much code
Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example :https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The first code block is all that’s needed to reproduce the problem and only includes the minimum code required to reproduce the problem. I followed the StackOverflow instructions to include steps I’ve taken to try to fix the problem. Perhaps this is distracting and better left out.

Comment: Have you tried without `executablePath` so pyppeteer downloads and uses the version of chromium it was designed for?

Comment: Also, one trick that might help you debug this. It prints events, including networkIdle (networkidle0) and networkAlmostIdle (networkidle2): `page._client.on('Page.lifecycleEvent', lambda e: print(e))`